# Preload Suggestions with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on an internal app that connects to filemaker and returns a bunch of results. It's a pretty big filemaker database, so it takes about 10 seconds to load all of the results.

Rather than the standard browser loading page, I'd ideally like to show some type of loading animation. I don't need a percent or any feedback of how far along the loading script is.

I figured the best way to handle this would be to load a page, and use ajax to go and fetch the data; however, I'm not too sure how to structure this in my routes.rb file.

...or if there is a better way to do this.

Everytime I've had to do this in the past it was with a external data feed or a static HTML file, so I'm really just looking for any suggestions/best practices you may have.

Thanks for reading!

PS- Using Ruby on Rails 4

Comment: It's not scalable to try to "load all the results" unless those are restricted to just the ones that fit on a page. It's usually easy to specify a particular offset and number of results to be returned, making it easy to walk through a table in page-sized chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would structure such a task

```
get '/your_route', to: 'controller#your_action', as: :named_route
```

in your controller

```
def your_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # this line will just load the page 
    format.json {render json: your_data_load.to_json} #this line will actually supply your data when you request a json response
  end
end
```

in your js.coffee file

```
$ ->
  #start your loading image
  $.getJSON '/your_route.json', (data) ->
    #populate the page with your data
  #remove your loading image
```

What this does is when the page is loaded it will render just the html page because of the `respond_to` block and then when the page is loaded it will start your loading image. It will then make a request to the same route but as a `json` request which will actually be supplying your information through the `respond_to` block as well. This json object will be contained in the data variable in your jQuery and you can process it however you need and then remove the loading image after it completes.

If you supplied more information my answer could be much less vague but that is the style I would utilize to process your request.

Comment: This was a lot simpler than I thought but does exactly

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds is a long time for a DB load that you're trying to display on-screen. Is it possible that your DB queries are far less efficient than you think? If you're new to Rails, consider looking at the console log as you hit the page to see exactly how many times you're hitting the DB. A common error is to load data with many small SQL queries rather than one large join that gets you exactly what you need.

If you are using ActiveRecord to connect to your database, look up eager loading, which may help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations